# A bound using primes

Tags: number-theory

> For a sufficiently large absolute constant $C$, there exists for every $n$ a prime number $r$ satisfying $(2\log{n})^6 \leq r \leq (C \log{n})^6, \text{ord}_{r}(n) > r^{\frac{1}{3}},$ and $P(r-1) > r^{\frac{2}{3}}$ where $P(m)$ denotes the largest prime divisor of an integer $m$.

I am trying to prove the above result, and my book says the below. I am wondering how they get $c\pi(x) \sim c\frac{C^6 \log{n^6}}{6\log(Cn)}$ since we should get $c\pi((C\log{n})^6) \sim c\frac{(C\log{n})^6}{\log{(C\log{n})^6}}$ and so I don't see if it is the same as what they have. Also other parts don't see right either so I am wondering how they are obtaining their results and if they are using the prime number theorem.

**Edit:** If someone could reproduce the book's solution in a way that doesn't have typos and makes more sense that would help.

My book is Introduction to Modern Number Theory by Yu. I. Manin.

**Book's solution:**

[image]

Comment: There seems to be a $\log$ omitted, yes. But it seems it's just a typo.

Comment: @quid Also in the numerator shouldn't it be $(C\log{n})^6$?

Comment: Yes the $\log n ^6$ there appear to be inteneded as $(\log n )^6$ not $\log(n^6)$.

Comment: @quid What about $\ll \dfrac{(\log{n})^6}{\log{\log{n}}}$? How did they get that? Shouldn't we just use the prime number theorem to get $\dfrac{(2\log{n})^6}{\log{(2\log{n})^6}}$?

Comment: That's just PNT; one can drop constants due to $\ll$ notation being used.

Comment: @quid How do we know it is $\ll$ and not $\gg$?

Comment: it is also $\gg$.

Comment: @quid I am confused. The notation $\ll$ means far less than, right? So how could it be far less than and far greater than?

Comment: No. It means Big Oh there see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation more specifically Vinogradov notation

Comment: so it says that the number of prime factors of $k$ is $< c\frac{\ln k}{\ln \ln k}$, hence the number of prime factors of $N = \prod_{j=1}^{x^{1/3}} (n^j -1)$ is $<c \sum_{j=1}^{x^{1/3}} \frac{\ln (n^j-1)}{\ln \ln (n^j-1)} <  c\sum_{j=1}^{x^{1/3}} \frac{j\ln n}{\ln (j\ln n)}$, but if for a prime $r$ : $o_r(n) < n^{1/3}$ then $r$ divides $n^{o_r(n)}-1$ hence it divides $N$, so there are at most $c\sum_{j=1}^{x^{1/3}} \frac{j\ln n}{\ln (j\ln n)}$ primes such that $o_r(n) < n^{1/3}$, and it concludes with saying they are more primes in $[1,C (\log n)^6]$. where is supposed to be the typo in this ?

Comment: @quid Can you explain the part about $r \leq x$ and $\text{ord}_r(n) \leq r^{\frac{1}{3}}$?

Comment: and the PNT they are using is that for a fixed constant $a$ , as $x \to \infty$ : $\pi(x)-\pi(ax)= (1-a)\frac{x}{\ln x} + o(x/\ln x)$

Comment: Sorry, no,  I do not wish to further delve into this.

Comment: sorry a mistake again !  $$\sum_{p | k} 1 < c \frac{\ln k}{\ln \ln k}$$ was correct. again with $k = \prod_{p < x} p$ you get $\ln k = \sum_{p < x} \ln p = \psi(x) \sim x$ hence $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\ln x}$ and since $x = \ln k$ you get that $\sum_{p | k} 1 \le \pi(\ln k) \sim \frac{\ln k}{\ln \ln k}$

Comment: it is true when $k$ is a primorial (of the form $\prod_{p < x} p$) and since those are the integers with the max number of prime factors it is true for every $k$. $\quad$ and yes you need the prime number theorem here (or at least a weaker version $\pi(x) < c \frac{x}{\ln x}$ if you don't care of $c$'s value, i.e. that any $c > 1$ works when $x$ is large enough)

Comment: @user1952009 Did you use the second Chebyshev function $\psi(x)$?

Comment: yes $\psi(x) = \sum_{p < x} \ln p$ which is $\sim x$ by the PNT, and $\sum_{p < x} 1 = \pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\ln x} \sim \frac{\psi(x)}{\ln \psi(x)}$  (as $x \to \infty$)

Comment: from here can you finish and write the answer yourself ? (with the maybe typos corrected, and the arguments explained in simple words)

Comment: @user1952009 I don't see how $\displaystyle \sum_{p < x} 1 = \pi(x)$. $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes.

Comment: in the context of number theory, $\sum_{p < x} $ is a notation for "sum on $p$ prime and $< x$ ". $\sum_{n \le x} = \lfloor x \rfloor$ while $\sum_{p \le x} 1 = \pi(x)$

Comment: @user1952009 I don't know what you mean by that, but I interpret it to mean the sum of prime numbers less than $x$.

Comment: $\sum_{p < x} 1$ is the number of primes $< x$ .. i.e. $\pi(x)$ when $x$ is not a prime..

Comment: @user1952009 I have never seen that notation before. Do you also mean the same for the product?

Comment: yes of course. and this notation is used everywhere, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product#Examples

Comment: what ??? I understand nothing. by definition $\sum_{p < x} f(p) = f(2)+f(3)+f(5)+\ldots $ and with $f(n) = 1, \forall n$ you get $1+1+1+\ldots$ i.e. the number of primes $< x$

Comment: I don't see how you get from $\displaystyle \sum_{p < x} 1 \sim \dfrac{\psi(x)}{\log{\psi(x)}}$ to $\displaystyle \sum_{p|k} 1 \leq \pi(\ln(k))$.

Comment: again because for a fixed $k$, the integer $\le k$ having the greatest number of prime factors is the greatest primorial $M = \prod_{p < x} p$ which is $\le k$. then write $\ln k \ge \ln M = \sum_{p < x} \ln p = \psi(x) = x + (\psi(x)-x)$  , hence $x + (\psi(x)-x) \le \ln k$ and because of the PNT $x \le (1+\epsilon)\ln k$. finally the number of prime factors of $M$ is $\pi(x) \le \pi((1+\epsilon)\ln k) \le C \frac{\ln k}{\ln \ln k}$, and it follows that the number of prime factors of $k$ is $\le C \frac{\ln k}{\ln \ln k}$ too